# Does playing a "Double Rent" card in Monopoly Deal count against your card play total on a turn?

Tags: monopoly-deal

According to the Action Card directions on a Double Rent card, it can *only* be played with a Rent card.

Given that it is the only card that cannot be played alone, does it count against your total cards played count for a given turn (which cannot exceed 3)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It counts as two cards out of your three for that turn. Taken from [the FAQ monopoly-game.net](http://monopoly-game.net/Classic_Monopoly_FAQ.html):

> Q - IF I USE A ‘DOUBLE THE RENT’ CARD WITH A STANDARD RENT CARD, DOES
>   THIS COUNT AS ‘PLAYING’ 2 CARDS, OR 1? A - This would count as 2 out
>   of the possible 3 cards you can play per turn.

Additional sources that confirm this:

- [MonopolyDealRules.com](http://monopolydealrules.com/index.php?page=rent#question-rent-2) on rules for Rent cards

Comment: that really needs to be in the rules supplied with the game :)

Comment: perhaps, then, it just needs to be written explicitly. Especially given you *cannot* use it on its own.